# What are the benefits and drawbacks of making a function that returns a pointer to a static global variable from another object file?

Tags: c

I am thinking of doing this because it suits my compartmentalization ideas, so I am trying to figure out if it is a good idea performance-wise.

```
// obj1.c
static char *data;

char* return_pointer_for_data() {
    return data;
}

// obj2.c
static char *buffer;

void copy_data_to_buffer(char* ptr) {
    buffer[5] = ptr[5];
}

// main.c
copy_data_to_buffer(return_pointer_for_data());
```

I would like to know the benefits and drawbacks of doing `return_pointer_for_data()`, and how common this approach is. The other approach I am thinking of is:

```
// obj2.c
void copy_data_to_buffer(char* ptr1, char* ptr2) {
    ptr1[5] = ptr2[5];
}  

// main.c
char *data;
char *buffer;
copy_data_to_buffer(buffer, data);
```

I have gotten answers about access speed comparison for copying data, ranging from "it highly depends" to "it doesn't matter", so I decided to base my decision on the benefits and drawbacks of `return_pointer_for_data()`.

Comment: Performance of what? Returning a pointer from a function? In the code you've shown none of the pointers are pointing to valid allocated memory so it really doesn't make sense or demonstrate what you might be concerned about.

Comment: Benefits are marginal, readability of the code:  terrible.

Comment: In `stdio.h`, `fopen()` does this, so it's not unheard of. But everywhere it's done, there are subtle rules to prevent unwanted interactions, and a lot of bug happen because someone forgets. Try to make your design fool proof and indestructable if you're doing that. If you're concerned about performance, the answer is always "benchmark it" and "ignore previous benchmarks" - too much is variable these days, from CPU caches to power settings.

Comment: @JohnBayko if performance matters at all. Beginners are obsessed with micro-optimizations

Comment: @0___________ I just had an idea. What if I make an extern variable that holds the pointer to the static variable? Would that be better or worse?

Comment: Always worse because it can easily lead to hard to debug errors

Comment: If the sole purpose of `return_pointer_for_data()` is to return a raw pointer to the static variable, then the benefits are basically non-existing. It would make more sense to expose **specific** functions that manipulate the static variable in a **controlled** way, that's a _very_ common pattern and often a good idea.

Comment: @iloveclang1 _"What if I make an extern variable that holds the pointer to the static variable?"_ I'm sorry but this is ridiculous, if you're going to `extern` a pointer to the variable, then you might as well declare the static variable globally. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Marco limiting the variable to the object file, obviously. But I need access to it at some point. So if I make it extern, then people will tell me how global variables are bad. What do you mean by "expose specific functions?"

Comment: @iloveclang1 I don't see _any_ real difference between exporting the variable and exporting a pointer to that variable. _A pointer is a variable after all._

Comment: If it is **global**, then there is no need to return it -- everything within that file-scope already has access to it. Now one justification would be for *convenience* or when returning one of several different global pointers depending on what is passed to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benefits:

1. Easy to share data over functions, you don't have to pass a `char*` every time you call a function.

Drawbacks:

1. If your program has multiple threads, it might result a race condition because multiple threads can write to it at the same time. You have to use a lock to protect it.
2. It can make your code hard to maintain when it grows. You need to careful order your function calls because they might need other function to set up the global variable.

Performance does not matter too much in this case, the first approach has an overhead of a function call.

Comment: Nice answer, I would add one more in the Drawbacks: Polutes namespace

Comment: `you don't have to pass a char* every time you call a function.` is it easier to call another function instead passing the parameter. disputable.

Comment: @0___________ OP means that there is no need to pass an argument as it is already declared globally, for instance: `form_set_title(form, "Hello")` vs `form_set_title("Hello")`

Comment: @DavidRanieri indeed, it may save your keyboard for sure

Comment: @0___________ I don't think it's a matter of writing more or less, it's a matter of design, for example, it doesn't make sense to pass the MySQL connection in hundreds of calls when you can save it once.

Comment: @DavidRanieri if makes any difference to the program, then yes, if not, then one should keep it clean.

Comment: @0___________ Well that's just what the answer says, if it does not involve protecting access to the variable with a mutex and does not alter the flow of the application, it is a benefit (small but it is)

Comment: @DavidRanieri mutex will cost you something as well flag, coherency, waiting queue - so I do not think that one will benefit from it.  On windows it is 150 to 15000 clocks.

Comment: @0___________ read again: _if it does **not** involve protecting access to the variable with a mutex ... it is a benefit_

Answer (score 2):

Do not think about micro-optimizations, think about the program design and architecture (+ algorithms)

[image: can see only one]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is the fundamental problem - assume the obvious problems (no memory allocated for the pointers) is fixed:

```
// obj1.c
static char *data;

char* return_pointer_for_data() {
    return data;
}

// obj2.c
static char *buffer;

void do_something_with_ptr(char* ptr) {
    buffer[5] = ptr[5];
    ...some stuff happens...
    // Reset for next time.
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(actual_buffer_size);
}

void im_new_here(char* ptr) {
    buffer = ptr;
    ...some stuff happens...
    // Reset for next time.
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(actual_buffer_size);
}

// main.c
// Bug - got to do this first.
i'm_new_here(return_pointer_for_data());
do_something_with_ptr(return_pointer_for_data());
```

If you don't see what happens, the first function clears whatever `ptr` is pointing to (and could overwrite the end and crash things), making it useless for further calls. What's to stop this from happening? Apart from going up and telling the new guy "That's not how things work here", because this might be years after you're doing something else and can't do that.

So if you want to do that, make your design foolproof and indestructable.